# How to start Kinect Laser data in Turtlebot without gmapping

Tags: navigation, kinect, laser, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

We would like to make a program for Turtlebot to avoid obstacle using Kinect Laser data.
We launched the minimal.launch file but the topic **/scan** is not published.
When we launch the gmapping demo, we found that the topic **/scan** becomes published and we can get laser data.

The question is whether it is possible to get laser data from Kinect on Turtlebot without having to run gmapping demo.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Anis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60602/how-to-start-kinect-laser-data-in-turtlebot-without-gmapping/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2013-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks Chad and Davesana

We tried the solution of Davesana first by executing the above launch file, but there was a problem that the /scan topic is still not published. However, we run the command

rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw

in another terminal, and it worked.

We also tried Chad solution.

when running the command
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch

it does not publish the /scan topic. Also, even when we executed the command

rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw

in another terminal. It did not worked too.

We actually replaced the command 3dsensor.launch by the command

roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

and it worked with the rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan.

Thanks

Anis

---

Originally posted by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) with karma: 253 on 2013-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2013-04-14**:
Both the solutions work. However, for more accurate data, it is better to use pointcloud_to_laserscan.

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-04-15**:
Hi Hemu, what issues are you seeing that cause inaccurate data for depthimage_to_laserscan?  It uses MUCH less CPU, and it's strongly recommended that it is used.  Please file an issue with a way to reproduce the inaccurate data: https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2013-04-15**:
Hi Chad, its true that depth image processing uses much less CPU. The data inaccuracy is specific to the application. For avoiding obstacles, I used (x^2+z^2 ) as the robot mostly moves in the x-z plane (taking kinect as the reference frame) as I wanted to find the distance between robot's base and

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2013-04-15**:
an object. The depth image to laserscan provides (x^2+y^2+z^2) which is the distance between the object and the kinect and not the distance between robot's base and object. Apart from this, there is no such inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For this you need to use PointCloud to LaserScan package. It comes with turtlebot stack. You need to create a launch file say kinect_laser.launch with below nodes:

```
<launch>
  <!-- kinect and frame ids -->
  <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>

  <!-- openni_manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="openni_manager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"/>

  <!-- throttling -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager">
    <param name="max_rate" value="2"/>
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"/>
    <remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

  <!-- fake laser -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/camera_depth_frame"/>
    <remap from="cloud" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

This will publish /scan topic without the need for gmapping. And then you can use this launch file in your slam.launch.

Hope this helps !!

P.S. Please make sure the name of openni launch file.. In my case it's present as mentioned in the above location.

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/depthimage_to_laserscan#depthimage_to_laserscan-1

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch

rostopic echo /scan
```

See the launch file here:
https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/master/turtlebot_bringup/launch/3dsensor.launch#L79

---

Or if you have the kinect up but not the laser, you can try:

```
rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw
```

http://www.ros.org/wiki/depthimage_to_laserscan#depthimage_to_laserscan-1

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5